# How to avoid keypad for particular input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic mobile app and if the user presses any input field the keypad opens; that's working fine. I have one datepicker with input field where I need to hide the keypad. How can I do this?

```
<div class="col">
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Date</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="bookdate" name="bookdate" id="txtstartdate" required="">
    </label>
    <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.bookdate.$error">
        <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#txtstartdate").datepicker({
            minDate: 3,
            maxDate: "+8M"
        });

    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean restricting user from entering value in date field?

Comment: make it readonly="true"

Comment: yes i want to restrict

Comment: `<input type="text" ng-model="bookdate" name="bookdate" id="txtstartdate" required=""  readonly="readonly" >`

Comment: is it possible to do validation using input type="date"

Comment: thanks guys its working

Answer (score 1):

Add readonly to the date input

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="bookdate" name="bookdate" id="txtstartdate" required="" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use date piker plugin for ionic.

http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionicdatepicker

Comment: i am getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'titleLabel' of undefined
    at link (http://localhost:8100/bower_components/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js:1:10231).please provide html and controller